# Как поменять цвет бургера?

Tags: html

Как поменять цвет полосок в бургере?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как их поменять на белый цвет в **CSS**?

Вот код

```
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-colour">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand"  href="index.html" ><img src="C:\Users\egord\Desktop\allproj\b5\images\logo.png" alt=""></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="pricing.html">Pricing</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Пробовал так :

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
    color: white;
}
```

не работает(

Comment: А что-то из этого пробовали? https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%3F&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

У `navbar-toggler-icon` внутри нет ни иконок ни символов. Эти полоски это картинка, которая вставлена с помощью background-image. Поэтому нужно убрать эту картинку и сделать самому эти полоски:

**Верхнюю и нижнюю полоски делаем с помощью `::before` и `::after`. Среднюю с помощью `span` который добавим внутри `navbar--toggler-icon`**

```html
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
    <span></span>
</span>
```

```css
.navbar-toggler-icon{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-image: none !important;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon span{
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
}
```